# pyspark dataframe api agg() function

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am wondering when to use agg when using the aggregation functions?
Why do I need to use agg here?

```
df.agg(mean(col("a"))).alias("b")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official doc [`agg`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.agg):

> Aggregate on the entire DataFrame without groups (shorthand for `df.groupBy.agg()`).

With an example :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("A", 1), ("A", 5), ("C", 6)], ["key", "value"])

df.show()
+---+-----+                                                                     
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|  A|    1|
|  A|    5|
|  C|    6|
+---+-----+
```

All these 3 statements are equivalent - they compute the mean over the whole dataframe.

```
df.agg(F.mean("value")).show()
+----------+
|avg(value)|
+----------+
|       4.0|
+----------+
```

```
df.groupBy().agg(F.mean("value")).show()
+----------+
|avg(value)|
+----------+
|       4.0|
+----------+
```

```
df.select(F.mean("value")).show()
+----------+
|avg(value)|
+----------+
|       4.0|
+----------+
```

---

If you specify the `groupeBy`, you change the output :

```py
df.groupBy("key").agg(F.mean("value")).show()
+---+----------+                                                                
|key|avg(value)|
+---+----------+
|  C|       6.0|
|  A|       3.0|
+---+----------+
```